# How to draw 3D surface plot of two functions with GNU plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

friends I'm trying to plot two functions in the same plot. I don't have any idea about how to plot(3D) in gnu plot. Here is my full description of function

```
 dgh:= 0.08792;
 Delta:=-0.32315;
 sx:= 0.02707;
 sy:= 0.00546;
 Esup:=sx*x+sy*y+dgh*((x^2+y^2)/2+Delta*(x^2-y^2)/2)^(1/2);
 Einf:=sx*x+sy*y-dgh*((x^2+y^2)/2+Delta*(x^2-y^2)/2)^(1/2);
```

my question is can plot this with gnu plot and if so, what are the steps for doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility for drawing your functions:

```
dgh = 0.08792
Delta = -0.32315
sx = 0.02707
sy = 0.00546
Esup(x,y) = sx*x + sy*y + dgh*((x**2 + y**2)/2 + Delta*(x**2 - y**2)/2)**0.5
Einf(x,y) = sx*x + sy*y - dgh*((x**2 + y**2)/2 + Delta*(x**2 - y**2)/2)**0.5

set isosamples 40
set hidden3d nooffset
set ticslevel 0
set view 79,28
splot Einf(x,y), Esup(x,y)
```

The result with version 4.6.3 and `set terminal pngcairo size 600,600` is:

[image]